# setState the showDialog() from outside flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to `setState` the `showDialog()` from the outside. The `showDialog()` shows how many images are uploaded to Firestore. But `setState` is not working because it doesn't change the state of `showDialog()`. Is there any way to change the state of showDialog() from outside??

Here is my code.

```
Future<void> _upload() async {
Reference storageReference;

showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      content: SizedBox(
        height: 150,
        width: 180,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            SpinKitRing(
              color: Color(0xff43b0e2),
              lineWidth: 10,
              size: 100,
            ),

            // here is the part I want to setState
            Text("$value/${widget.imagelist.length + 1}",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff43b0e2),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                    fontSize: 18.0),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.9),
    );
  },
);

for (File image in widget.imagelist) {
  storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('project/' +
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid +
      "/" +
      widget.title +
      "/" +
      image.path.toString().split("/").last);

  await storageReference.putFile(image);
  String downloadURL = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
  setState(() {
    imglist.add(downloadURL);
    value += 1;
  });
}
storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('project/' +
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid +
    "/" +
    widget.title +
    "/thumbnail");
await storageReference.putFile(widget.thumbnail);
String thumbnailURL = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
setState(() {
  value += 1;
});

await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Gallery').add({
  "author": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
  "bookmark": <String>[],
  "description": widget.description,
  "image": imglist,
  "liked": <String>[],
  "time": Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()),
  "title": widget.title,
  "visited": 0,
  "is18": widget.is18,
  "object": widget.objlist,
  "tool": widget.toollist,
  "thumbnail": thumbnailURL,
  "tag": widget.taglist,
  "platform": widget.platform,
});

Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

}

Comment: use provider ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use valueNotifier
when image uploaded make notifier.value++;
and  in showDialog add widget :

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
  valueListenable:notifier,
  builder:(ctx,value,child){
   return Text("$value/${widget.imagelist.length + 1}",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff43b0e2),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                    fontSize: 18.0),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center);
 }
);
```